# Zend Date MySQL Timezone offset problem

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, date

I've got a site which uses the Zend Framework.  There's a form which the users fill in, including a Date field.  Currently I'm using this to create a new Zend_Date object and then getting the date in ISO format to put into the MySQL database.  However when the date is returned in ISO format it also has the timezone offset appended to the end (e.g. 2011-01-01T00:00:00-0500), which MySQL doesn't like.  When I try to add it to the DB it gives me an invalid date error.  I'm sure there must be a simple solution to return the date without the timezone offset, but I can't seem to find it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question should go a little deeper than just that - mySQL can't store time zone information in DATE fields, so you'll have to define which time zone you want to store your dates in the database. Then, you can do the necessary conversions and formatting

Answer (score 1):

if you toString your Zend_Date object and then use the mb_strcut() function to remove the timezone and then insert it into the db it should be fine ?

another way would be to alter the Zend function that returns the date in an ISO format to prevent it from appending the timezone to the end of the date.